# Idiomatic way to get array of column values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe where I want to get a single array of all of the values in the 'a' column, which is part of a multi-index dataframe. The code below works, but it is hard to read, write, and think about. Is there a more idiomatic way to express the same idea?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3]})
y = pd.DataFrame({'a': [11, 12, 13], 'b': [21, 22, 23]})

df = pd.concat({'x': x, 'y': y}, axis=1)

x = np.concatenate(df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'a')].values)
```

```
df:
   x      y
   a  b   a   b
0  1  1  11  21
1  2  2  12  22
2  3  3  13  23

x:
[ 1 11  2 12  3 13]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach 1: `xs`

```
np.ravel(df.xs('a', level=1, axis=1))
```

Approach 2: `stack`

```
list(df.stack(0)['a'])
```

Result

```
[1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13]
```

Answer (score 1):

To slice `MultiIndex` and avoid `slice(None)`, you can use [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html) then chaining with `flatten` or `ravel`:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice  # alias as suggested by documentation

x = df.loc[:, idx[:, 'a']].values.flatten()  # or.ravel()
```

Output:

```
>>> x
array([ 1, 11,  2, 12,  3, 13])
```